# SSD vs Memory upgrade

Tags: mac

I am starting to learn XCode, and having a MacBook Pro 2011 with 4Gb of DDR3 ram (Quad Core 2.0 Ghz), it is slow. Am considering of upgrading either my RAM or swapping the HDD for an SSD.

Which would you recommend first and why?

Comment: Why have us guess if you are IO constrained or RAM constrained? Open up Activity Monitor and let's see what your bottleneck is. :-) Since RAM lets you have more processes running without slow IO impacting you some workloads need more RAM and others benefit from faster IO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSD's improve the start-up and shut down speed and will load apps installed on it a bit faster. 
More ram will be very useful if you are running multiple big apps like xCode at the same time.

I recently upgraded my SSD and I have upgraded my ram before that and both made my machine a lot faster, the SSD with booting and the ram with running apps.

It really depends on what you would like to speed up in your mac.
If you are not sure I would recommend more Ram since it is less of a hassle, cheaper and the performance boost is very noticeable especially when developing in Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Since the SSDs have gone cheaper I would pick one of these first.
You could also upgrade both ofcource.

If you need a lot of space, you might to check OptiBay for Mac, so you can remove SuperDrive and add a second HDD/SDD in your Mac.

I recently bought a new MBP Retina 13 inch with 4GB RAM and 256GB SSD, I hardly see difference between SSD and 8GB which I've had before in an older Macbook Pro 2009.